# "id" not get parsed in codeigniter view to controller

Tags: codeigniter

View page,here id can't get parsed here some error displayed likeMessage: Undefined variable: row &&Message: Trying to get property of non-object

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('Insert_ctrl/update/'.$row->id.'');?>" method="post">


<?php  
foreach ($g as $row)  
{  

?> 
<label>ID</label>
<input type="text" name="id" value="<?php  echo $row->id;?>"><br>
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="dname" value="<?php  echo $row->student_name;?>"><br>
```

here is my Controller page

```
    function edit($id)
    {
        $data['g'] ="";           
        $this->load->database();                
        $this->load->model('Inserts_model');  
        $data['g'] =$this->Inserts_model->select_row($id);   
        $this->load->view('update_view', $data); 
    }
```

here is my model page

```
public function select_row($id)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get('student');
    return $query->result_object();
}
```

here is another controller function update ie goes after form get executed

```
function update($id)
        {
                if(isset($_POST['update']))
                    {
                        $data = array
                        (
                        'student_name' => $this->input->post('dname'),
                        'student_email' => $this->input->post('demail'),
                        'student_mobile' =>  $this->input->post('dmobile'),
                        'student_address' => $this->input->post('daddress')
                        );
                        $this->Inserts_model->update($data,$id);
                        redirect('Insert_ctrl/index');
                    }
        }
```

Comment: can we see the querying function in the model please?

Comment: echo `$id` in your controller and check. `echo $id; exit;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you try to get single record from database then you should use `row()` instead of `result()`

```
public function select_row($id)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get('student');
    return $query->row(); //use row() instead of result
}
```

You method name is `edit` and you submit form of `update` method

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('Insert_ctrl/edit/'.$g[0]->id.'');?>" method="post">
```

If you are passing  `id` with `input` then you does not need to send with `URL`

You should try with this `$this->uri->segment(3);`

Comment: @jibinkj can you plz show your `$g` of foreach() with `print_r()`

Comment: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [student_name] => jibinkj [student_address] => 2222222222 [student_email] => jibinkj@gmail.com [student_mobile] => ss [id] => 17 ) )

Answer (score 0):

if you are querying for a single row, then you better use `row_array()`:

```
return $query->row_array();
```

and then you will be able to access the array indexes like:

```
echo $row['id'];
```

Comment: No,return $query->result_object(); in model page